# SQL Query: Current and Previous month values in two columns

Tags: sql, zoho

Need a SQL Query to have Previous month values against to the monthly values.

**Constraint**: DO NOT USE ANY LAG, OVER, PARTITION, Row_number() etc. Use only LEFT, RIGHT or INNER Joins and achieve it.

I have a table as follows

```
LoanID1 Jan   2000  
LoanID1 Feb   3000  
LoanID1 March 2500  
LoanID1 April 1000  
LoanID1 May   500   
LoanID2 Jan   750   
LoanID2 FEB   3500  
LoanID2 March 2700  
LoanID2 April 1500  
LoanID2 May   4000
```

Basically, These are Monthly values for each LoanID, what i need is i need to have another column with the Previous month values like the following table:

```
LoanID1 Jan   2000  
LoanID1 Feb   3000   2000
LoanID1 March 2500   3000
LoanID1 April 1000   2500
LoanID1 May   500    1000
LoanID2 Jan   750    
LoanID2 FEB   3500   750
LoanID2 March 2700   3500
LoanID2 April 1500   2700
LoanID2 May   4000   1500
```

I tried with Joining the same table but could not achieve it. Please guide me and throw me some light how can i make it.

Update to provide actual details:

Illustration images: the actual data how it is available and how i need it in the 2nd image

[This is the actual database with the records looks like

[image: This is the actual database with the records looks like]

This is what i need with another column(Previous Month Values)

[image: This is what i need with another column(Previous Month Values)]

---

Appreciate your guidance and thanks in advance.

Comment: Proper columns make sample data easier to read.

Comment: Have you tried to do a SQL subquery selecting the value where the LoanID is the same, but using reverse order? Assuming you have some index or value that's increasing where you can base your reverse order

Comment: @UmadharM . . . Are months really stored as strings?  Is Zoho a database?

Comment: Might I suggest not using tabs in your data if you care about the formatting being at all readable?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Months is a Date format like '01 Nov 2016 00:00:00.000000' or '01 Nov 2016' Just for the example i gave months in the example to get the sample query, so that i thought i can build on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on RDBMS you are using, you need to add a "row number" column ordered by date, based on which you would perform join.
It will look like this

```
select
t1.month,
t1.value as curr_mon_val,
t2.value as prev_mon_val
from 
(select t1.month, t1.value, row_number from t1) as t1
join (select t1.value, row_number from t1 where row_number > 1) as t2
on t1.row_number = t2.row_number-1
```

this is approximation to what you need to write depending on your RDBMS

Comment: Thank you for the idea query, what is the row_number? Should i maitian any other index for row number?

Comment: No, row number is a field that you should generate using row_number(date) function (again depending on RDBMS can look different), passing to it some date, like month start date or sting like '201802'.

Comment: Hi Alex, Maybe you will get more idea, have given two image screenshots, please take a look, i have a string of month start date. https://prnt.sc/igy3ab and Only the particular loan records image: prntscr.com/igy3xi . So with the start date how does it help?

Comment: Ok, Should i generate & get month number in numeric in another column? like MONTH(startdate date)?

Comment: If your RDBMS has row_number() function, you can simply pass date as date format to it. The idea is to have a column with explicit order of rows based on logic you desire. Here we need it to be ordered by date, so you can pass date in it. So in result for Jan 2018, Feb 2018, Mar 2018 you would get: 1,2,3

Comment: I tried to get row numbers but when a Jan 2018 or Jan 2017 will have same row number as 1. I tried with Group by and order by also but it is giving thousands of duplicate records probably multiplying. Just checking if we need to apply any condition.

Comment: forgot to tell row_number() function is not available in Zoho. reports . but I tried with date function to get month number but not sure what is the issue as I am getting 1000 of duplicates coming.

Comment: I've never worked with Zoho, don't know specifics. From googling seems like it doesn't have such functionality. Do you have some DB underneath or it runs its own Zoho DB? You can't do the trick with months numbers so easily as you need uninterrupted sequence of numbers: [1,2,3,4...] You can try to create such sequence by playing with dates, like to get sequential month_num you can year*12+month for Jan 2000 = 2000*12 +  1 = 24001, Feb 2000 = 24002... doesn't start from 1, but is sequential.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function

```
    declare @myt table (id nvarchar(50),monthnames nvarchar(50),amount int)

insert into @myt

values

('LoanID1','Jan', 2000       ),
('LoanID1','Feb', 3000       ),
('LoanID1','March',   2500   ), 
('LoanID1','April',   1000   ), 
('LoanID1','May', 500        ),
('LoanID2','Jan', 750        ),
('LoanID2','Feb', 3500       ),
('LoanID2','March',   2700   ), 
('LoanID2','April',   1500   ), 
('LoanID2','May', 4000       )

select *,LAG(Amount,1,0) Over(partition by ID order by id,MonthNumber) as PreviousMonth  from (
select *,Month(cast(monthnames+'1 2018' as date)) as MonthNumber from @myt
)x
```

Comment: Thank you PlaidDK, LAG is not available in Zoho Reports.

Comment: I dont think anyone knows what Zoho is

Comment: It's called Zoho Reports which I am using for BI reporting. Its new tool and domain for me. It uses SQL queues with some limitations.

Comment: Sounds to me you need some kinda of data warehouse instead of building ad-hoc queries in a tool that has too many limits.